# parsing an array of elements in xml using java

Tags: java, xml, spring, sax

Here, I'm using SAX method for parsing array. I'm facing an issue where I'm not able to write a generic code to parse an array type of xml. I couldn't find a solution for generic way methodology to identify it as an array and iterate over it and store it in List

```
<bookstore>
  <book category="children">
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title>Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Any solution will help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use code below. I got it from: https://github.com/niteshapte/generic-xml-parser

```
public class GenericXMLParserSAX extends DefaultHandler {

    private ListMultimap<String, String> listMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    String tempCharacter;   
    private String[] startElements;
    private String[] endElements;

    public void setStartElements(String[] startElements) {
            this.startElements = startElements;
    }

    public String[] getStartElements() {
            return startElements;
    }

    public void setEndElements(String[] endElements) {
            this.endElements = endElements;
    }

    public String[] getEndElements() {
            return endElements;
    }

    public void parseDocument(String xml, String[] startElements, String[] endElements) {
            setStartElements(startElements);
            setEndElements(endElements);

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            try {
                    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();                      
                    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());                     
                    sp.parse(inputStream, this);
            } catch(SAXException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
            } catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
                    pce.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void parseDocument(String xml, String[] endElements) {           
            setEndElements(endElements);

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            try {
                    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();                      
                    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());                     
                    sp.parse(inputStream, this);
            } catch(SAXException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
            } catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
                    pce.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            String[] startElements = getStartElements();

            if(startElements!= null){
                    for(int i = 0; i < startElements.length; i++) {
                            if(qName.startsWith(startElements[i])) {                                
                                    listMultimap.put(startElements[i], qName);
                            }
                    }       
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            tempCharacter = new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {                
            String[] endElements = getEndElements();

            for(int i = 0; i < endElements.length; i++) {
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(endElements[i])) {
                            listMultimap.put(endElements[i], tempCharacter);                
                    }
            }
    }

    public ListMultimap<String, String> multiSetResult() {            
            return listMultimap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Handler that extends [DefaultHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) and use it to parse your XML and generate the `List<Book>` for you.

The Handler will maintain a `List<Book>` and:

- every time it will encounter the book **start** tag, it will create a new `Book`
- every time it will encounter the book **end** tag, it will add this `Book` to the List.

In the end it will be holding the complete list of Books and you can access it via its `getBooks()` method

Assuming this Book class:

```
class Book {
    private String category;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String year;
    private String price;
    // GETTERS/SETTERS
}
```

You can create a custom Handler like this:

```
class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private boolean title = false;
    private boolean author = false;
    private boolean year = false;
    private boolean price = false;

    // Holds the list of Books
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    // Holds the Book we are currently parsing
    private Book book;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, Attributes attributes) {

        switch (qName) {
            // Create a new Book when finding the start book tag
            case "book": {
                book = new Book();
                book.setCategory(attributes.getValue("category"));
            }
            case "title": title = true;
            case "author": author = true;
            case "year": year = true;
            case "price": price = true;
        }
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {
        // Add the current Book to the list when finding the end book tag
        if("book".equals(qName)) {
            books.add(book);
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
        String value = new String(ch, start, length);

        if (title) {
            book.setTitle(value);
            title = false;
        } else if (author) {
            book.setAuthor(value);
            author = false;
        } else if (year) {
            book.setYear(value);
            year = false;
        } else if (price) {
            book.setPrice(value);
            price = false;
        }
    }

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }
}
```

Then you parse using this custom Handler and retrieve the list of Books

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();
saxParser.parse("/path/to/file.xml", myHandler);
List<Book> books = myHandler.getBooks();
```